# Adding more than one document to a PrinterJob

Tags: java, pdf, printing

I use the following method to print pdf files in a program I am using.  It works, but I have to call the method each time I want a single page to print.  So if I want to print the same document five times, this entire method must execute five times.  My question is, is there some way to add more than one document to the PrinterJob so that this method can be called exactly once to print out what I need?

```
public static void printPdf(File thePdf)
{
    File f = thePdf;
    RandomAccessFile fis = null;
    FileChannel fc = null;
    ByteBuffer bb = null;
    try 
    {
        PrintService  service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

        fis = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rw");
        fc = fis.getChannel();
        bb = ByteBuffer.allocate((int) fc.size());
        fc.read(bb);
        PDFFile pdfFile = new PDFFile(bb); 
        PDFPrintPage pages = new PDFPrintPage(pdfFile);
        PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        pjob.setPrintService(service);

        PageFormat pf = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob().defaultPage();

        pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);

        Paper paper = new Paper();

        paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, paper.getWidth() * 2, paper.getHeight());

        pf.setPaper(paper);

        pjob.setJobName(f.getName());

        Book book = new Book();
        book.append(pages, pf, pdfFile.getNumPages());
        pjob.setPageable(book);
        pjob.print();

    } 
    catch (IOException|PrinterException e) 
    {
        ShowErrors.show_errors("Printing exception: "+e.toString());
    } 
    finally 
    {
        try
        {
            if (fc != null) 
                fc.close();
            if (fis != null) 
                fis.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Exception closing IO channel: "+e.toString());
        }

        if (bb != null) 
        {
            bb.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

It would be perfect if I could pass this method an array of File objects and add each one to pjob (I'm guessing that's where you would add them, if that's possible).  I've looked through the documentation and it honestly is rather confusing to me.  If anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is not runnable, here's my best guess as to printing multiple files with multiple copies.

```
public void printPdf(List<File> pdfFiles, int copies) {
    PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    RandomAccessFile fis = null;
    FileChannel fc = null;
    ByteBuffer bb = null;
    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < pdfFiles.size(); i++) {
            File f = pdfFiles.get(i);
            fis = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rw");
            fc = fis.getChannel();
            bb = ByteBuffer.allocate((int) fc.size());
            fc.read(bb);

            for (int j = 0; j < copies; j++) {
                PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
                pjob.setPrintService(service);

                PageFormat pf = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob().defaultPage();
                pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);

                Paper paper = new Paper();
                paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, paper.getWidth() * 2,
                        paper.getHeight());
                pf.setPaper(paper);

                PDFFile pdfFile = new PDFFile(bb);
                PDFPrintPage pages = new PDFPrintPage(pdfFile);
                pjob.setJobName(f.getName());

                Book book = new Book();
                book.append(pages, pf, pdfFile.getNumPages());
                pjob.setPageable(book);
                pjob.print();
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (PrinterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fc != null)
                fc.close();
            if (fis != null)
                fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception closing IO channel: "
                    + e.toString());
        }

        if (bb != null) {
            bb.clear();
        }
    }
}
```